# How to reduce duration of apk generation with flutter?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, apk

I am experiencing very long apk generation time (14 984 seconds to be accurate) for a 500 lines of code program, so I am wondering if I am doing something wrong.

I am using flutter, the flutter build apk --split-per-abi command.

My program uses a very long list (330 000 items, each one of them is a word), this list is declared and set in a separate dart file.

Previously, the list was shorter, about 130 000 items, and the generation time was around 15 minutes.

I am curious to know if the generation time has something to do with this huge list, if it does, what is the best way to optimze the generation time ?

Comment: So to clarify, when you say "14 984", do you mean fourteen-point-nine-eight-four seconds or fourteen-thousand-nine-hundred-eighty-four seconds (i.e. over 4 hours)?

Comment: Yes, over four hours indeed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the best way to optimize the generation time ?

Move the large list out of your Dart code. Instead, store it in an external file like JSON, and load it at runtime. That would at least reduce the compilation load.
If the list is essential at compile time, consider splitting it across multiple files and loading them as needed.

If feasible, consider implementing lazy loading for your list. Load only the necessary items as needed, rather than the entire list at startup.

```dart
// Load list from an external file at runtime
Future<List<String>> loadList() async {
  final data = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/wordlist.json');
  return (json.decode(data) as List).map((e) => e.toString()).toList();
}
```

And use Flutter's incremental builds (using [`dartdevc`](https://dart.dev/tools/dartdevc)) by only rebuilding parts of the app that have changed.

---

[abion47](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1255873/abion47) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77816651/how-to-reduce-duration-of-apk-generation-with-flutter/77816775#comment137186056_77816775)

> If the list is a simple list of strings, it would be better to have it in a text file with each item on its own line. It's far faster to read a text file and separate it into lines than to run a JSON parser for a list file with over 300k items.

`words.txt`:

```
word1
word2
...
word330000
```

True: if the list consists solely of strings, using a plain text file with each item on a separate line is indeed more efficient than JSON because:

- parsing a plain text file is much faster and requires less processing power than parsing a JSON file. JSON parsing can be resource-intensive, especially with a large amount of data.
- A plain text file consumes less memory because it does not have the additional formatting and syntax required by JSON (like quotes around strings and commas between items).
- Managing and updating a plain text file is straightforward, especially if the data changes frequently or needs to be edited manually.

A Dart code to load that list would be:

```dart
Future<List<String>> loadList() async {
    final data = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/words.txt');
    return data.split('\n');
}
```

---

> But if I do so, do I need to join the txt file with the apk, or is there a way to somehow 'include' the txt file within the apk file?

In Flutter, you can indeed "include" the text file within the APK. That is done by adding the file to your Flutter project and then specifying it in the `pubspec.yaml` file. That way, the file becomes part of the app's assets and is bundled into the APK when you build the app. Here is how you can do it:

First, you should place your `words.txt` file in an appropriate directory within your Flutter project, like `assets/`.
You need to update your `pubspec.yaml` file to include the text file as an asset. That tells Flutter to bundle the file with your app.

```yaml
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/words.txt
```

You can then load the text file in your Dart code as shown previously:

```dart
Future<List<String>> loadList() async {
  final data = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/words.txt');
  return data.split('\n');
}
```

Bundling the file with your app makes sure it is always available, regardless of the user's internet connection. However, it also means that you need to release a new version of your app every time you update the file. If you want to avoid that, you can download the file from a server instead. That way, you can update the file on the server without having to release a new version of your app.

---

> Anyway, I did not manage to get it working: the `loadlist` function returns a `Future`, and I am struggling trying to loop accross it (flutter complains it is not iterable or the getter length is not defined). I need somehow to cast it to a regular list because that the way I use it across my program.
> By the way I have added `import 'dart:async'; import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;` at the top of my program)

Since `loadList` returns a `Future<List<String>>`, you need to make sure the Future is resolved *before* you can use the list in a synchronous context (like looping through it). See "[Asynchronous programming: futures, async, await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)"

When you call `loadList`, you need to `await` the Future to get the actual `List<String>`. That means the calling function should be `async` as well.

```dart
Future<void> useList() async {
   List<String> myList = await loadList();
   // Now you can loop through myList
   for (String word in myList) {
      print(word);
   }
}
```

If you are using this list in Flutter widgets, you might need to use a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to handle the asynchronous nature of the data.

```dart
FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
   future: loadList(),
   builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
         return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
      }
      // Data is loaded, you can now use snapshot.data
      return ListView.builder(
         itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
         itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ListTile(
            title: Text(snapshot.data![index]),
            );
         },
      );
      } else {
      // Show a loading indicator while waiting for the data
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
   },
)
```

Make sure to handle cases where the data might not load correctly. For example, the Future might complete with an error (e.g. if the file is not found).

---

> This `Future` thing was too complicated for me so I went for `readAsStringSync()` instead, it is more convenient for my need.

[`readAsStringSync()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/readAsStringSync.html) is the synchronous counterpart of [`readAsString()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/readAsString.html): it reads the entire file contents as a string and blocks the calling thread until the operation is complete. That means the execution of your program will halt until the file is fully read.

Warning: synchronous operations can lead to blocking the main thread, resulting in a poor user experience due to UI freezing or jank.

But, if the OP still prefers to use `readAsStringSync()`, that would look like:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

List<String> loadListSync() {
  // Ensure you have the path to your file correctly set.
  // This example assumes the file is in the root of your project folder.
  final file = File('assets/words.txt');
  String data = file.readAsStringSync();
  return data.split('\n');
}

void useList() {
  List<String> myList = loadListSync();
  // Now you can loop through myList
  for (String word in myList) {
    print(word);
  }
}
```

Comment: If the list is a simple list of strings, it would be better to have it in a text file with each item on its own line. It's far faster to read a text file and separate it into lines than to run a JSON parser for a list file with over 300k items.

Comment: @Abion47 True. Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Yes, I understand, it was my first intention, but if I do so, do I need to join the txt file with the apk, or is there a way to somehow 'include' the txt file within the apk file? (Maybe this question sounds stupid to you, but I started to use flutter 10 days ago...)

Comment: Thank you a lot.  Anyway I did not manage to get it working: the loadlist function returns a Future and I am struggling trying to loop accross it (flutter complains it is not iterable or the getter length is not defined. I need somehow to cast it to a regular list because that the way I use it across my program. By the way I have added import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle; at the top of my program,

Comment: Thank you. This Future thing was too complicated for me so I went for readAsStringSync() instead, it is more convenient for my need.

Comment: @baptiste OK, that should work too.

Comment: @baptiste I have edited the answer to include your approach. Let me know if I missed anything.